# Tikz/pgfplot plots on a example, but not in the main text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am getting really confused with this error. I have a pgfplot which works flawless on an example minidocument. However, when I translate it to the main document I am writting it just does not work and gets me this error message:

Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'plots/scattered_example.da\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details). {plots/scattered_example.dat};

The picture is there and works, I have loaded the same packages (the only one that I need actually is in common, pgfplots}... So maybe there is a dependence that is breaking it. This is the code (which works), in case somebody wants to try it. The template where it does not work can be found here:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-bristol-thesis-template/kzqrfvyxxcdm#.V4wMyPl96Co

THANKS!!

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir}
    %\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
    %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{comment}
    %\usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}



    \begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
            at={(0.5,-.4)},
            anchor=south}}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Cooling effectiveness},
    ylabel={Radius [mm]},
    xmin=0.68, xmax=0.98,
    ymin=110, ymax=145,
    width=15cm,
    height=7cm,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    %enlargelimits=false,
        legend columns=2,
    ]
    \addplot[
    %scatter,
    red,
    mark=square*,
    mark size=0.1pt]
    table[meta=30]
    {scattered_example.dat};
    \addlegendentry{DAHole 50 g/s Unsteady}

    \addplot[
    %scatter,
    black,
    mark=square*,
    mark size=0.1pt]
    table[meta=30u]
    {scattered_example2.dat};
    \addlegendentry{DAHole 50 g/s Steady}

    \addplot[
    %scatter,
    red,
    mark=x,
    mark size=1.5pt]
    table[meta=50u]
    {scattered_example4.dat};
    \addlegendentry{DAHole 30 g/s Unsteady}

    \addplot[
    %scatter,
    black,
    mark=x,
    mark size=1.5pt]
    table[meta=50]
    {scattered_example3.dat};
    \addlegendentry{DAHole 30 g/s Steady}
    %Ojo Las gr=aficas estan bien, pero las etiquetas en el fuente mal!!!! 
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems, that you haven't defined path to table used in pgfplots. Two simple solution cross my mind: (i) include your graph as pdf image with `includegraphics` or  (ii) include table into image. Examples, how to do this you can find in pgfplots manual.

Comment: OTOH, you could just copy the table into the same folder as the document.

Comment: Note that questions should be self-contained. They should not depend on external links. There is code here, but it is not code which anybody can use to reproduce the problem.